# Handling All Nodes Down in Cassandra when using DataStax C# Driver

Tags: c#, azure, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a simple two node cluster setup in Azure and I'm using the DataStax C# driver to connect to it.

I am able to take a single node down without any issues. As long as I have one node running all is well. However if I take both nodes down and then bring a node back up the driver never catches on to this. It keeps saying all hosts were tried and could not be queried even though a node is available again.

I imagine this is a rare scenario for someone with 20 nodes, but having only two nodes and a limited budget at the moment, I have to plan for this possibility. I have a worker role in Azure that is always running and I need a way to reconnect   (or refresh the connection) to get the C# driver to see a node is available again. I don't want to have to restart my service every time something like that happens.

I do not see any great way to know from the exception that I need to reconnect as it could be a temporary error and I don't see any obvious properties on the Cluster or Session object to know I need to reset the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataStax C# driver exposes a [ReconnectionPolicy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/common/drivers/reference/tuningPolicies_c.html) interface and delivers some builtin implementations to configure how the driver will try to reconnect when a node goes down.

For example, configure the `Cluster` try to reconnect to nodes considered as down after 500ms passed:

```
Cluster.Builder()
   .WithReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(500))
   .Build()
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. If you are doing one off queries is it best to call Cluster.Shutdown() after every query to free up the connection? Or is it fine to just leave the connection open?

Comment: You should call `Cluster.Shutdown()` once in your app lifetime, ideally after no more queries have been issued.